# Perform weighted and stratified logistic regression in R

Tags: r, regression, survey, gtsummary, weighted

I'm trying to perform a stratified logistic regression using weighted data. The regression seems to be working fine, but I'm having trouble displaying the stratified results. Previously, when I conducted univariate regressions with the same dataset, I used `tbl_uvregression()` and it worked well. However, I'm unable to achieve the same with `tbl_regression()`. Even when I use `summary()`, it only provides a single result.

I'm providing some fictitious data that resembles my dataset, in case anyone has encountered this issue before.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
library(survey)

gender <- factor(c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2))
age <- factor(c(3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1))
prema.5cl <- factor(c(5, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2))
meduc.4cl <- factor(c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2))
mhealth <- factor(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0))
parttime <- factor(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0))
ref1 <- factor(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0))
ref2 <- factor(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0))
ref3 <- factor(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
poids <- c(0.52, 1.43, 0.74, 1.60, 1.71, 0.08, 0.96, 1.62, 1.00, 0.83, 1.74, 0.82, 1.23, 1.04, 0.19, 1.63, 0.45, 0.08, 0.60, 1.73)
gd <- factor(c("gp_2", "gp_1", "gp_2", "gp_1", "gp_2", "gp_1", "gp_1", "gp_1", "gp_2", "gp_2", "gp_1", "gp_1", "gp_2", "gp_1", "gp_1", "gp_2", "gp_2", "gp_1", "gp_2", "gp_2"))
bth_2y <- factor(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
db <- data.frame(gender, age, prema.5cl, meduc.4cl, mhealth, parttime, ref1, ref2, ref3, poids, gd, bth_2y)

reg1 <- svyglm(
  bth_2y ~ gender + age + prema.5cl + meduc.4cl + mhealth + ref1 + ref2 + ref3,
  family = quasibinomial,
  design = svydesign(id=~1, data = db, weights = ~poids, strata = ~gd))

summary(reg1)

tbl_regression(reg1)
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Why are you expecting more than one result?  As far as I know `strata` just informs about how the data was collected.

Answer (score 1):

That code produced what I would have expected: it asks for a single logistic regression model with five predictors. You don't say what you were looking for.

At a guess, perhaps you had one of the other meanings of "stratified" in mind?  In `svydesign`, the strata are population subsets where the sample size is fixed by design (a stratified *sample*).  There's another usage of "stratified" to mean that you want analyses conducted separately for different subpopulations.  If that's what you mean, you want something like

```
design<-svydesign(id=~1, data = db, weights = ~poids, strata = ~gd)
reg1 <- svyglm(
  bth_2y ~ gender + age + prema.5cl + meduc.4cl + mhealth + ref1 + ref2 + ref3,
  family = quasibinomial,
  design = subset(design, gd=="gp_1"))
summary(reg1)
tbl_regression(reg1)

reg2 <- svyglm(
  bth_2y ~ gender + age + prema.5cl + meduc.4cl + mhealth + ref1 + ref2 + ref3,
  family = quasibinomial,
  design = subset(design, gd=="gp_2"))
summary(reg2)
tbl_regression(reg2)
```

This doesn't actually work in your example data because it's too small; some of the covariate combinations don't appear. It should work in your real data.

If `gd` really aren't sampling strata you would need to omit the `strata=~gd` part of the `svydesign` call

Comment: Thank you very much; it does indeed work. There's no way to do it all at once; you must necessarily go through two regressions on subsets, correct?

Comment: Not efficiently, when you want the `tbl_regression` output.  For many analyses, `svyby` will do it.